# Powershell to Read a CSV then split one of the strings at commas but not if inside Quotes

Tags: powershell

So first what I'm trying to do 
I've got a CSV file which has a list of arguments to be passed to Robocopy

I open this with Import-csv and pass it on to robocopy - I have found there are folders I can't copy - so to stop errors I exclude them  - but found that I need to split them before I pass them to robocopy. What I want to be able to do is quote them similar to the CSV quoting- so that the split does not split inside quotes
so split ("My Documents,""Bad, Path""")  gives

```
My Documents
Bad, Path
```

Rather than

```
My Documents
Bad
Path
```

I was thinking a possible path to investigate is to pipe it through some CSV like  processing - I'm not sure where to start to find a command which would do that

This is my test code

```
import-csv "R:\t.csv" | where { $_.class -eq "PC1" } | % {
$_.DirExclusions
$_.FileExclusions
  $DirExclusions = $_.DirExclusions
  $FileExclusions = $_.FileExclusions
  $DirExclusions 
  $FileExclusions
  if ($DirExclusions -ne "" )  { $XD ="/XD" } 
  if ($FileExclusions -ne "" )  { $XF ="/XF" } 
  robocopy "$($_.Folder)" "R:\Backups\TEST" *.* /r:0 /w:1 $XD $DirExclusions.split(",") $XF $FileExclusions.Split(",") 
}
```

The CSV file

> Class,Folder,DirExclusions,FileExclusions PC1,C:\Users\e156479,".*,My
>   Documents,""Hard, Path""",*ntuser*

The output showing what it excluded

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Jun 14 14:07:32 2018

   Source : C:\Users\e156479\
     Dest : R:\Backups\TEST\

    Files : *.*

Exc Files : *ntuser*

 Exc Dirs : My Documents
            Hard
            Path
            .*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:0 /W:1
```

The actual code changes the paths so that the \ and C$ type shares are processed so that the Backup path is consistent for all source directories  - I've removed all that processing so as to make my problem obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$myLine = 'Class,Folder,DirExclusions,FileExclusions PC1,C:\Users\e156479,".*,My Documents,""Hard, Path""",ntuser'
$myLine -replace '""(.*),(.*)"""','$1#$2' -split ',' -replace '#', ','
```

If '#' should not possible for any reason, you can use another dummy-delimiter, e. g. "!"

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks - use a regex to find the , inside the quotes - change it to something (#) which is nowhere in the string , split it - then change it back   -  yes of course

Comment: I'm not sure of the quoting - in the end I used   
$DirExclusions = $DirExclusions -replace """(.*),(.*)""",'$1#$2'  -split ','  -replace '#', ','
OR
  $DirExclusions = $DirExclusions -replace '"(.*),(.*)"','$1#$2'  -split ','  -replace '#', ','